# How to add two pandas data frames and keep both indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vector

What is the most elegant and efficient way of adding two pandas data frames and keep both indexes?

**Table 1**

| Index | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 | 0.5 | 1.0 |
| Sample2 | 0.0 | 0.5 |

**Table 2**

| Index | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample3 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Sample4 | 1.0 | 1.0 |

**Result Table**

| Index | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Sample1, Sample3] | 0.5 | 2.0 |
| [Sample2, Sample4] | 1.0 | 1.5 |

```
import pandas as pd
table_one = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0.5, 1.0],
                          'Col2': [0.0, 0.5]},
                          index=['Sample1', 'Sample2'])
table_two = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0.0, 1.0],
                          'Col2': [1.0, 1.0]},
                          index=['Sample3', 'Sample4'])
table_result = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0.5, 2.0],
                          'Col2': [1.0, 1.5]},
                          index=[['Sample1','Sample3'], ['Sample2','Sample4']])
# Please insert solution here...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
out = table_one.add(table_two.set_axis(table_one.index))
out.index = zip(table_one.index, table_two.index)
```

Generalization to an arbitrary number of tables:

```
from functools import reduce

tables = [table_one, table_two]
idx = list(zip(*(d.index for d in tables)))
out = reduce(lambda a, b: a.add(b), (d.set_axis(idx) for d in tables))
```

Output:

```
                    Col1  Col2
(Sample1, Sample3)   0.5   1.0
(Sample2, Sample4)   2.0   1.5
```